# How do I return files as base-64 data URL strings from my API using MongoDB/GridFS?

Tags: html, reactjs, mongodb, async-await, gridfs

I have a collection of Contacts inside my MongoDB

[image]

Those Contacts have avatars (or "profile pictures")

Here is the profile picture for the above user:

[image]

... and a chunk of that file (there's only one).

[image]

I'm trying to take ^^^ that ^^^ chunk and parse it into a base-64 data URL in order to return it from my server back to my application and use it inside an `<img>`'s src attribute.

```
app.get('/queryContacts', (req, res) => {
  const getContacts = async query => {
    let contacts = await db
      .collection('contacts')
      .find(query)
      .toArray();
    return contacts;
  };

  const getImages = async id => {
    let imageUrl = 'data:image/jpg;base64';

    await bucket
      .openDownloadStream(new ObjectID(id))
      .on('data', chunk => {
        imageUrl += chunk.toString('base64');
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        return imageUrl;
      });
  }

  getContacts({account_id: new ObjectID(req.query.id)}).then(contacts => {
    Object.keys(contacts).forEach(key => {
      getImages(contacts[key].image_id).then(url => {
        console.log(url); // undefined
        contacts[key].imageUrl = url;
      });
    });

    res.json(contacts);
  });
});
```

**The problem is that when I try this, the URL is `undefined` because `getImages()` isn't waiting for the `'end'` event to finish.**

Comment: Please do not add images of your code, but actual code with [code fences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). If the images become unavailable, your question becomes meaningless. Furthermore, you make it harder for people to help you. In order to provide you with working code, they would have to type all of it instead of merely changing it.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I updated the question. For the record, I created another endpoint that gets the file and pipes it to the response, but I would still like to get this working as I believe it's a performance optimization. I could be wrong.